# error while saving the .pkl models of linear regression

Tags: python, django, machine-learning

I am coding a web application using the framworks django ,the problem is when saving my learning model of linear regresion as .pkl. 
Is it necessary to create the empty .pkl file or does it generate automatically? and how can I read the contents of such a .pkl file?

```
# Libraries

# Importing Dataset
```

````
    data = pd.read_csv('ml_code/ml_process/test.csv')
    data.fillna(0, inplace=True)


    def handle_non_numerical_data(df):
        columns = df.columns.values

        for column in columns:
            text_digit_vals = {}

            def convert_to_int(val):
                return text_digit_vals[val]

            if df[column].dtype != np.int64 and df[column].dtype != 
    np.float64:
                column_contents = df[column].values.tolist()
                unique_elements = set(column_contents)
                x = 0
                for unique in unique_elements:
                    if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                        text_digit_vals[unique] = x
                        x = x + 1

                df[column] = list(map(convert_to_int, df[column]))

        return df

    data = handle_non_numerical_data(data)
    data = data.as_matrix()

    #X matrice des var. explicatives
    X = data[:,0:9]
    #y vecteur de la var. à prédire
    y = data[:,9]

    X2_train, X2_test, y2_train, y2_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
    test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

    lreg = LinearRegression()

    lreg.fit(X2_train, y2_train)
    print('Accuracy of linear regression on training set: 
    {:.2f}'.format(lreg.score(X2_train, y2_train)))
    print('Accuracy of linear regression on test set: 
    {:.2f}'.format(lreg.score(X2_test, y2_test)))
    y_pred2 = lreg.predict(X2_test)
    print("Predicted Sales: %.3f" % (y_pred2[0]))
    ```   


Saving the Logistic Regression Model
````

```
linear_regression_model = pickle.dumps(lreg)
```

```
Saving the model to a file
```

```
joblib.dump(linear_regression_model,'ml_code/linear_regression_model.pkl')
```

```
I get this error when I run the application
```

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'ml_code/linear_regression_model.pkl'
```

Comment: You should use ```w```rite, not ```r```ead: 
```with open(filename, 'wb') as f:```

Comment: this instruction is automaticly in packages sklearn, it's not me who integrates it into my code